# Should I make edits immediately after receiving feedback when asking for improvements on meta?

Tags: support, edits, feedback

I made [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427969) on Stack Overflow Meta, asking if there's anything wrong with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77903659/13625293). Not long after, there's a comment giving feedback for improvement to my answer. I found this feedback useful and thought it could be applied directly.

Should I immediately edit my answer according to that feedback, or should I let it be as it was at the time I asked the meta question, so that people don't need to view the edit history to know what I was initially talking about (and possibly introduce some confusion)?

Comment: You can give a link to a specific non-first version that you so identify that you can get after clicking on 'edited', or indicate that you are talking about the 1st version. Then you can keep improving your main post as soon as possible. Just keep your meta post clear & updated. If your main post gets deleted you can append it in your meta post. Often people edit in images of deleted posts, and this is better if the content is socially questionable, but otherwise text is best given as text. I suggest appending after a horizontal rule rather than quoting because the editor quotes poorly.

Comment: @philipxy That's a good answer.

Answer (score -2):

I would do it, because it's way easier to find a solution if the question is clearly formulated. Making others see the edit history would indeed make things more confusing.

Comment: The question is about updating an answer, and I don't think the edit history has anything to do with it. Can you clarify?

Comment: i am sorry that i confused you the part  _the edit history is confusing_ is the answer to the folowing part of the question  _so that people don't need to see the edit history_